# i want to create common key for some values in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner to JavaScript. i want to create a common key for some values in JavaScript object. For example, in the below code we have a employee name with some tasks assigned to them, so i have created the tasks as nested object. Now i feel that this is looking like a basic level code. is there any way to achieve this effectively?. Also i want to know how to retrieve nested object's value in function.

```
const taskInfo = [
  {
    name: "john",
    mail: "mailid",
    task1: { taskname: "name", priority: 2, groupname: "name" },
    task2: { taskname: "name", priority: 2, groupname: "name" },
    task3: { taskname: "name", priority: 2, groupname: "name" }
  },
  {
    name: "smith",
    mail: "mailid",
    task1: { taskname: "name", priority: 2, groupname: "name" },
    task2: { taskname: "name", priority: 2, groupname: "name" }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it could be done something like this:

```
taskInfo =  [
        {name: 'John Doe', mail:'john@test.com', tasks: [
                {name:'Task1', priority: 1, groupname: 'gName'},
                {name:'Task2', priority: 1, groupname: 'gName1'},
                {name:'Task3', priority: 1, groupname: 'gName2'},
            ]
        },
        {name: 'Susan Doe', mail:'susan@test.com', tasks: [
                {name:'Task4', priority: 1, groupname: 'gName'},
                {name:'Task5', priority: 2, groupname: 'gName2'},
                {name:'Task6', priority: 3, groupname: 'gName2'},
            ]
        }
    ]
```

To loop through the array have a look at this:
[Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: yes, i have tried this. but i am facing some issues to retrieve data from the inner array. could you help me on this?

Comment: Try this: taskInfo[0].tasks[0].name

Comment: i want to retrieve value of priority from inner tasks array and push that into separate empty array. it is kind of destructuring. i have tried using some array.prototype.methods, but end up with undefined error .could you help me on this?

Comment: the value of priority would be:  taskInfo[i].tasks[j].priority you just need to assign that value to an array: newArray[] = taskInfo[i].tasks[j].priority (i and j are the temp variables)

Comment: really sorry..couldn't achieve. should i use nested for loop to get this value...since i am new to javascript couldn't understand. could you provide the sample loop to retrieve the data.

Comment: I edited my answer to include how to loop through an array in JS

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as valid if everything is working.